# How to memoize recursive functions?

Tags: recursion, ocaml, memoization

Consider a recursive function, say the Euclid algorithm defined by:

```
let rec gcd a b =
  let (q, r) = (a / b, a mod b) in
  if r = 0 then b else gcd b r
```

(This is a simplified, very brittle definition.)  How to memoize such a function?  The classical approach of defining a high-order function `memoize : ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'b)`
adding memoization to the function is here useless, because it will only save time on the first call.

I have found details on how to memoize such function in Lisp or Haskell:

- [How do I memoize a recursive function in Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/256507/4013143)
- [Memoization with recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9410330/4013143)

These suggestions rely on the ability found in Lisp to overwrite the symbol definition of a function or on the “call-by-need” strategy used by Haskell, and are therefore useless in OCaml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The winning strategy is to define the recursive function to be memoized in a *continuation passing style*:

```
let gcd_cont k (a,b) =
  let (q, r) = (a / b, a mod b) in
  if r = 0 then b else k (b,r)
```

Instead of defining recursively the `gcd_cont` function, we add an argument, the “continuation” to be called in lieu of recursing. Now we define two higher-order functions, `call` and `memo` which operate on functions having a continuation argument.  The first function, `call` is defined as:

```
let call f =
    let rec g x =
      f g x
    in
    g
```

It builds a function `g` which does nothing special but calls `f`.  The second function `memo` builds a function `g` implementing memoization:

```
let memo f =
    let table = ref [] in
    let compute k x =
      let y = f k x in
      table := (x,y) :: !table; y
    in
    let rec g x =
      try List.assoc x !table
      with Not_found -> compute g x
    in
    g
```

These functions have the following signatures.

```
val call : (('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>
val memo : (('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>
```

Now we define two versions of the `gcd` function, the first one without memoization and the second one with memoization:

```
let gcd_call a b =
  call gcd_cont (a,b)

let gcd_memo a b =
  memo gcd_cont (a,b)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# let memoize f =
    let table = Hashtbl.Poly.create () in
    (fun x ->
      match Hashtbl.find table x with
      | Some y -> y
      | None ->
        let y = f x in
        Hashtbl.add_exn table ~key:x ~data:y;
        y
    );;
val memoize : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>


# let memo_rec f_norec x =
    let fref = ref (fun _ -> assert false) in
    let f = memoize (fun x -> f_norec !fref x) in
    fref := f;
    f x
  ;;
val memo_rec : (('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>
```

You should read the section here: https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/imperative-programming-1.html#memoization-and-dynamic-programming in the book *Real World OCaml*.

It will help you truly understand how `memo` is working.

Comment: How does this answer improves Michael Grünewald's answer?

Comment: @AdèleBlanc-Sec Pointed out a formal explanation from the book `real world ocaml`. It really explains in details how `memo` works. Honestly, `continuation passing style` in Michael's answer is a bit complicated or misleading if one doesn't really understand what is `continuation passing`