# How to convert CPS-style gcd computation to use the Continuation Monad

Tags: ocaml, monads, continuations

Let us consider the following implementation of the Continuation monad, for CPS-style computations yielding and integer:

```
module Cont : sig
  type 'a t = ('a -> int) -> int
  val return : 'a -> 'a t
  val bind : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t
  val callCC: (('a -> 'b t) -> 'a t) -> 'a t
end = struct
  type 'a t = ('a -> int) -> int

  let return x =
    fun cont -> cont x

  let bind m f =
    fun cont -> m (fun x -> (f x) cont)

  let callCC k =
    fun cont -> k (fun x -> (fun _ -> cont x)) cont
end
```

How can we rewrite the CPS-style implementation of gcd computation (see [How to memoize recursive functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704901/how-to-memoize-recursive-functions/25705254#25705254)) and especially the memoization to take advantage of the Cont monad?

After defining

```
let gcd_cont k (a,b) =
  let (q, r) = (a / b, a mod b) in
  if r = 0 then Cont.return b else k (b,r)
```

I tried to use the type solver to give me cue about the type that the memoization function should have:

```
# let gcd memo ((a,b):int * int) =
  Cont.callCC (memo gcd_cont (a,b)) (fun x -> x)
;;
    val gcd :
  (((int * int -> int Cont.t) -> int * int -> int Cont.t) ->
   int * int -> (int -> 'a Cont.t) -> int Cont.t) ->
  int * int -> int = <fun>
```

However I could not turn this hint into an actual implementation. Is someone able to do this?  The logic behind using “callCC” in the memoization function is that if a value is found in the cache, then this is is an early exit condition.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like the issue is that in his answer to [How to memoize recursive functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704901/how-to-memoize-recursive-functions/25705254#25705254), Michael called CPS style what is not CPS style. In CPS style, the extra continuation argument `k` is used whenever one wants to return a value - the value is then applied to `k` instead.

This is not really what we want here, and not what implements:

```ocaml
let gcd_cont k (a,b) =
  let (q, r) = (a / b, a mod b) in
  if r = 0 then b else k (b,r)
```

Here, `k` is not used for returning (`b` is returned directly), it is used instead of performing a recursive call. This unwinds the recursion: within `gcd_cont`, one can think of `k` as `gcd_cont` itself, just like if `let rec` was used. Later on, `gcd_cont` can be turned into a truly recursive function using a fixpoint combinator, that basically "feeds it to itself":

```
let rec fix f x = f (fix f) x
let gcd = fix gcd_cont
```

(this is equivalent to the `call` function that Michael defines)

The difference with defining `gcd` directly using a `let rec` is that the version with unwinded recursion allows one to "instrument" the recursive calls, as the recursion itself is performed by the fixpoint combinator. This is what we want for memoization: we only want to perform recursion if the result is not in the cache. Thus the definition of a `memo` combinator.

If the function is defined with a `let rec`, the recursion is closed at the same time as defining the function, so one cannot instrument the recursive call-sites to insert memoization.

As a side note, the two answers basically implement the same thing: the only difference is the way they implement recursion in the fixpoint combinator: Michael's fixpoint combinator uses `let rec`, Jackson's one uses a reference, i.e. "Landin's knot" — an alternative way of implementing recursion, if you have references in your language.

Sooo, to conclude, I'd say implementing that in the continuation monad is not really possible / does not really make sense, as the thing was not CPS in the first place.

Comment: My bad for naming CPS what is not. Is there any canonical name for the specific form of the “instrument-able” version of the functions?